# double free or corruption (!prev) httpd

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, cpython

My server crashed due to zero space. I've added more space. 
Since then my apache server is restarting every few minutes/ hours.

My stack is  `apache -> python (a pip that servers the files.)`

The memory leak can be at apache or at python

```
*** Error in `/usr/sbin/httpd': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x00007f28dc67a6f0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7c503)[0x7f28d9746503]
/usr/lib64/libpython3.5m.so.1.0(PyThreadState_DeleteCurrent+0x40)[0x7f28cd50e420]
/usr/lib64/libpython3.5m.so.1.0(+0x165075)[0x7f28cd529075]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7dc5)[0x7f28d9c96dc5]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f28d97c173d]
```

The `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` contains:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py35.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

What can I do to debug/solve this?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a leak, but a bug. See https://serverfault.com/a/169886/20171

Comment: @FredLarson thanks for the quick response. I saw that answer. It makes little sense since the issue didn't exist before.. it started after the disk space issue.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the cause for this can be hard as it is likely in some third party module for Python that has a C extension component. Two things I would suggest.

First ensure you are using mod_wsgi daemon mode..

Second ensure you are setting:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

The latter can help fix problems where Python extension modules aren't written correctly to work with Python sub interpreters. When they aren't they can cause crashes and deadlocks.

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#python-simplified-gil-state-api

You can find details on daemon mode in the documentation:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/configuration-guidelines.html#defining-process-groups
- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIDaemonProcess.html
- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html
- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/processes-and-threading.html

Comment: how do i ensure `mod_wsgi daemon mode`? where do i check ?